# .NET Framework and .NET 6 compatibility (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

I have a solution with several projects that use .NET Framework 4.7.2. One of the projects contains all of my Entity Framework models and the `DbContext` (EF v6.4.4). It also uses the `ASPNet.Identity.EntityFramework` (v2.2.3) extensions.

The projects contains an API layer, common layer (shared DTO models, helper functions, etc), WebJob project, and a Unit Test project.

I need to add in an Azure Function project to process messages from a service bus queue (which receives messages from our ERP system) and update our front facing e-commerce web app.

I need to get with the times and get more familiar with .NET Core / Standard project types. My issue is that the Azure Function project is using .NET 6.0. I want to reference my Entity Framework project.

I have been reading that with later version of .NET Core / Standard, there is "more" compatibility between those and .NET Framework projects.

I was able to reference everything in my Azure Function project and get it to compile with not much issue. However, when I go to do anything with the Entity Framework (read from the DB or write), I get an exception like this:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: InboundFunctions. EntityFramework: The type initializer for 'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception. System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key').

After digging some more, I seem to have an issue with the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package. I had to include this in my AZ function project to satisfy the implementation of the `IdentityDbContext`. According to VS, this is the library that is throwing a warning about compatibility issues.

[image: VS 2022 Screen shot]

At the moment, I am not sure how to resolve this. Would it be easier to make a new `DbContext` for just the .NET Core stuff or is there a better approach? I don't need any of the Identity stuff in my Azure functions project - it's really only used in my API layer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: According to my experience you should rewrite your DbContext fro eFCore especially if you have big/complicated/performance critical project. Multiple things are changed and nothing exists out there to migrate them automatically.

Comment: You can use .NET Framework with Azure Functions